# MVC Anti forgery token validating even though no [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, cookies

I have the dreaded Validation of viewstate MAC failed problem from time to time. I run my application in a web farm and have set the machine key of the application to the same value on all web servers. 
I have been doing some experiments and now I have two questions regarding the anti forgery token mechanism: 
1. I seem to get this error even though I'm not calling any action with the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute (the problem seems to appear when rendering the token in the view). Why is this happening? Isn't the validation supposed to only run when the attribute is present. The problem dissappears if the __RequestVerificationToken  cookie is removed.

2. Isn't the __RequestVerificationToken cookie supposed to be a session cookie and thus be invalid as the session expires? This doesn't seem to be the case?

Stack trace:

> A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.AntiForgeryDataSerializer.Deserialize(String
>   serializedToken) 
>  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.GetAntiForgeryTokenAndSetCookie(String salt,
>   String domain, String path) 
>  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken(String salt, String domain,
>   String path) 
>  at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken()
>   
>  at
>   ASP.views_customer__customerlogin_ascx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer) 
>  at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) 
>  at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) 
>  at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
>  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
>  at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   
>  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   
>  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
>  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl.ViewUserControlContainerPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context) 
>  at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.RenderView(ViewContext
>   viewContext) 
>  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl.RenderViewAndRestoreContentType(ViewPage
>   containerPage, ViewContext viewContext) 
>  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String
>   partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter
>   writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection) 
>  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(HtmlHelper
>   htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model) at
>   ASP.views_cart_index_aspx.__Rendercontainer_main(HtmlTextWriter __w,
>   Control parameterContainer) 
>  at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) at
>   ASP.views_shared_site_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w,
>   Control parameterContainer) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) 
>  at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) 
>  at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
>  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at
>   ASP.views_cart_index_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
>  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3()
>   
>  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1
>   func) 
>  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action
>   action) 
>  at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler,
>   TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage,
>   VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception
>   error, String queryStringOverride)

**Inner exception**

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a
>   Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies
>   the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot
>   be used in a cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Only actions decorated with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute verify the token and may raise this exception.
2. `__RequestVerificationToken` cookie has no relation to any session and never times out. The verification consists of checking the equality of the cookie value with the POSTed value from the hidden field.

Comment: If you look at the stack trace I updated the question with, this doesn't seem to be entirely true.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the `AntiForgeryToken` HTML helper checks for the presence of the cookie and tries to deserialize its value. This is where the exception occurs. It seems that the cookie was encrypted with a machine key which is different than the machine key used to decrypt it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the explanation. I'm still confused to why someone would want to validate the cookie upon rendering.

Comment: @Markus, in fact they are not validating the cookie, they are just trying to deserialize the value in order to reuse it if present. It is at the moment of deserialization that the exception occurs.